# How to delimit and write file contents to vector?

Tags: c++, vector

So let's say I have a vector of ints and a text file which looks like this:

```
1|2|3|4|5
```

How can I add the numbers to the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would open the file using `std::ifstream`. There are a few ways you could then read these out, but one example would be to use `std::getline` with a custom "end of line" character, being your `|` in this case:

```cpp
std::vector<int> myVect;
std::ifstream reader("./file.txt"); //Replace with path to your file

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::string item;
    std::getline(reader, item, '|'); //The third argument tells it to read until a '|' char
    int item = std::stoi(item); //Convert from string to int
    myVect.push_back(number);
}
```

This example relies on you knowing how many elements you want to get, but can be modified to work with an unknown size.

Comment: What does the stoi() function do? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have added it to the answer. stoi() converts the input (a string) to an integer. Be sure to mark this answer as a solution if it solved the question.

Comment: I can't mark as solved right now because I will test the code tomorrow!

Comment: You could use a `char` variable to read the separator:  `std::cin >> number1 >> separator >> number2 >> separator >> number3 >> separator >> number4 >> separator >> number5;`  Search the internet for "C++ comma separated values".

Comment: Or, you can use `cin >> number` in a loop and use `cin.ignore()` to skip the `|`s without reading them.